# Can I control how tidyjson joins nested arrays?

Tags: r, json, tidyverse

It seems as though [tidyjson](https://cran.r-project.org/package=tidyjson) uses an *inner-join*-like behaviour on nested arrays, thus dropping records with empty child arrays. Is there a way to get *left-join*-like behaviour instead, filling with `NA`s?

For example, these fake data have one record with a populated nested array (`middles`) and two records where `middles` is empty:

```
library(tidyjson)

people <- c('{"age": 32, "name": [{"first": "Bob",   "last": "Smith", "middles":[{"middle1":"John", "middle2":"Rick"}]}]}',
            '{"age": 54, "name": [{"first": "Susan", "last": "Doe", "middles":[]}]}',
            '{"age": 18, "name": [{"first": "Ann",   "last": "Jones", "middles":[]}]}')
```

From these data I wish to have a dataframe with all the parent records retained and missing child-array information filled with `NA`s (~ left join) as such:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
    age first last  middle1 middle2
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>   <chr>  
1    32 Bob   Smith John    Rick   
2    54 Susan Doe   NA      NA
3    18 Ann   Jones NA      NA
```

However, extracting a nested array with some empty child arrays causes loss of their parent's information (~ inner join):

```
people %>% 
    spread_all() %>%  
    enter_object("name") %>% gather_array() %>% 
    spread_all() %>% select(-document.id,-array.index) %>% 
    enter_object("middles") %>% gather_array %>% 
    spread_all()  %>% select(-array.index) %>% 
    tbl_df()
```

```
# A tibble: 1 x 5
    age first last  middle1 middle2
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>   <chr>  
1    32 Bob   Smith John    Rick
```

Is there a way to avoid this; i.e., to retain all the rows even when child arrays are empty?

---

#### A workaround but not a solution

A possible workaround is to literally do a left join, but this means duplicating the JSON read, which is not trivial given gigabytes of data.

```
wrap_dplyr_verb <- function(dplyr.verb) {

    # Creates a tidyjson verb out of a dplyr verb
    # https://github.com/colearendt/tidyjson/blob/master/R/tbl_json.R

    function(.data, ...) {

        # Check if reserved ..JSON name already in data.frame
        if ("..JSON" %in% names(.data))
            stop("'..JSON' in the column names of tbl_json object being filtered")

        # Assign JSON to the data.frame so it is treated as any other column
        .data$..JSON <- attr(.data, "JSON")

        # Apply the transformation
        y <- dplyr.verb(dplyr::as_tibble(.data), ...)

        # Reconstruct tbl_json without ..JSON column
        tbl_json(dplyr::select(y, -..JSON), y$..JSON)

    }
}
left_join_json = wrap_dplyr_verb(left_join)
```

```
people %>% 
    spread_all() %>%  
    enter_object("name") %>% gather_array() %>% 
    spread_all() %>% select(-document.id,-array.index) %>% 
    left_join_json(
        people %>% 
            spread_all() %>%  
            enter_object("name") %>% gather_array() %>% 
            spread_all() %>% select(-document.id,-array.index) %>% 
            enter_object("middles") %>% gather_array %>% 
            spread_all()  %>% select(-array.index)
    ) %>% 
    tbl_df()
```

```
Joining, by = c("age", "first", "last")
# A tibble: 3 x 5
    age first last  middle1 middle2
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>   <chr>  
1    32 Bob   Smith John    Rick   
2    54 Susan Doe   NA      NA     
3    18 Ann   Jones NA      NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for asking this question! It's definitely an interesting use case and one that I think could be improved upon within `tidyjson`.

Of course, I forgot that I [had already worked with you on this question in GitHub](https://github.com/colearendt/tidyjson/issues/117), so I implemented with a different pattern here, in case it's any help to you or others. Basically, the idea is to go "tall" instead of "wide" first. I have no idea what it does to execution time, and whether or not there are left joins hidden in here that hurt the timing.

```r
library(tidyjson)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

people <- c('{"age": 32, "name": [{"first": "Bob",   "last": "Smith", "middles":[{"middle1":"John", "middle2":"Rick"}]}]}',
            '{"age": 54, "name": [{"first": "Susan", "last": "Doe", "middles":[]}]}',
            '{"age": 18, "name": [{"first": "Ann",   "last": "Jones", "middles":[]}]}')

as_tbl_json(people) %>% spread_all() %>% enter_object("name") %>% gather_array("nameid") %>%
  gather_object("key") %>% 
  {bind_rows(
    filter(., key != "middles") %>% append_values_string("value"),
    filter(., key == "middles") %>% gather_array("middleid") %>% 
      select(-key) %>%
      gather_object("key") %>%
      append_values_string("value")
  )} %>%
  # drop tbl_json
  as_tibble() %>%
  select(-document.id, -nameid, -middleid) %>%
  # could also use tidyr::pivot_wider
  tidyr::spread(key, value)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>     age first last  middle1 middle2
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>   <chr>  
#> 1    18 Ann   Jones <NA>    <NA>   
#> 2    32 Bob   Smith John    Rick   
#> 3    54 Susan Doe   <NA>    <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>